# Getting "Unable to configure Firebase App : unrecognized selector sent to instance" on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

After days of surfing the net without any solution, I decided to ask my question here.

I'm using Firebase for a project and I can't get it to work properly on iOS. My app works on Android and PC but on IOS I get the following error when starting the app:

```
ERROR: Unable to configure Firebase app (-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2816b9a40)
can't initialize app : Firebase.InitializationException:  Firebase app creation failed.
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.FirebaseApp+CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

I check the dependencies before calling Firebase and I don't get any error.

Also, my app crashes when I call `DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;`

Then I get the following message :

```
An update was requested for an unkown participant: (null), with client context: <SBFTraitsArbiterUpdateContext: 0x280aad8f0>
```

Do you know where this error can come from? I have read all the Firebase documentation but I can't find the origin

Don't hesitate to ask me if you need further information.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I post my solution under your question although I'm not sure if it fits to your problem. One month later you probably found another way. But maybe others will find it helpful.

I had a similar error when trying to add Firebase Dynamic Links.

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
    reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: 
    unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2823640c0'
    terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The debugging halted in function

```
    FIRDLAddToAllowListForCustomDomainsArray
```

The problem is the key FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains in the Info.plist. It needs to be an array of Strings, not just a String.